# Prerequisites for Geneterating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Well Ill try to be as short as I can - I have an exam in descrete maths, but sadly our discrete maths course isnt compatible with general courses because it has other stuff included in the course aswell. I have prepaired the entire exam 3 times for now, but every time I had just 1 part left that I couldnt finish, which is recurent relations and generating functions. I complete all the other parts and get so overwhelmed when I get to this one that I cant even describe it. **The problem is that there is so much stuff I know nothing about, that I dont even know where to start**. I passed my calculus exam without deep study, just did it to pass the exam and that left me crippeled for many courses to come. I do have planned to revisit the Calculus parts from scratch, but now its simply not the time because the deadlines are coming closer. **I need to know, in detail, which are the prerequisites that I must learn before being able to tackle generating functions, because just knowing what I have to do would make the whole thing so much easier.** Study resources are welcome aswell, but I dont want to be greedy here. Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The main prerequisite for ordinary generating functions would be a concrete understanding of **sequences**, **Sigma notation / manipulation** and the various closed form expressions for common sums, **basic differential calculus** including **Taylor Series** and knowing what a **power series** is.

Assuming you have a decent Maths background you shouldn't have too much trouble in covering / refreshing these topics in a day or so.

I would also add that while not a prerequisite, an understanding of Recurrences (Divide & Conquer and Linear) may help you understand why Generating Functions are used.

MIT have a great 25 page document on Ordinary Generating Functions that you may find helpful. It is part of their wider Discrete Mathematics course.
[Link here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap12.pdf)